# How to stop Sony Xperia Z3 Compact making noise on using camera button?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, sony-xperia-z3-compact

I've got a Sony Xperia Z3 Compact running Android 5.0.2, and is not rooted, which has a button that instantly wakes the phone going straight into the camera app.

One problem - unless Media Volume is at zero, pressing the camera button makes a distracting and annoying tinkling sound.

It does this **despite the fact that**:

- **I already have "Sound" turned off in Camera settings**. This turns off noises like the shutter sound, but doesn't stop the camera button sound. It seems the phone thinks "camera sounds" and "camera button sounds" are completely unrelated things.
- I've turned off all the Sound options under the phone's system settings.

How can I turn off this specific "camera button" sound? I've looked through the system settings but can't find anything relevant.

Right now my "workaround" is to always turn media volume to zero after every time I do something which uses it, but this is far from ideal.

Comment: Just a side note: there used to be (and perhaps still is) a push to *require* a phone camera to make some sort of noise when taking a picture. Privacy reasons.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of that debate, but to be clear, this isn't when taking a picture, this is when starting up the camera app (and only when doing so using the physical camera button, and only when media volume is not zero). It's definitely not a privacy feature.

Comment: Damn.... just keep finger on speaker and turn your camera on. This worked for me several times :D.................

Comment: Are you using Lollipop, or is the device rooted? I can try to make good use of my answer [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/116969/96277). Tasker can trigger an action if the Camera button is tapped, so I would activate Zen Mode immediately. Since I don't have any Sony device I'd primarily rely on your feedback.

Comment: It's Android 5.0.2, and it isn't rooted (and I'd prefer not to root if possible)

Comment: @user568458 Please use '@firelord'. I didn't get your comment notification in my inbox. Anyhow, that answer I linked can also work for non-rooted devices. I did mention it at the bottom. Did you try it? It could work.

Comment: @firelord not able to test currently but will try it if no simple solution emerges

Comment: I agree with @Firelord, Tasker could be a good option. You'd have to test, though, to see if it's quick enough to mute the Media volume before the tinkling. You definitely don't have to root or run a shell command just to mute the volume when an app fires.

Comment: I know you said you prefer not to root if possible. So throwing my rooted option out there just in case you end up having to root. Found this on xda. http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2492852

Comment: @jer3my thanks, and the fact that someone went to the trouble of making that tool makes me suspect this is not possible without rooting :-( dammit, why do so many hardware companies make basic UI mistakes when they make software, like "don't make unnecessary sounds that can't be turned off"...

Comment: @user568458 Well in some states(USA) its illegal to take photos with a device that doesn't make a sound when taking pictures.

Comment: In those countries and states it's the **shutter sound** that can't be turned off. Not one specific shortcut to the app that only exists on one company's phones. This question is not about the shutter sound and has nothing whatsoever to do with those laws which don't exist in my country.